# Holomorphic function $h(x+iy)$ for x>0

Tags: complex-analysis

$$h(x+iy)=x^x+iv(x,y)$$ for $x>0$ where $v$ is real function

can h be holomorphic? if yes, why?

As far as i understand, for a function to be holomorphic,it must be possible to infinitely differentiate the function.But i am a little confused with harmonic functions too. Can someone explain that elegantly, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be an easy application of the Cauchy reimann equations. 
For a function $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, we know that its holomorphic if and only if
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

And
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

The second equation is easy to work with for us, because $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$. So $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$ also. So $v$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Now let $h(x) =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $. I only care that $h$ doesn't depend on $y$ and it is not constant. Then $h(x)= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$. So $v(x,y)= y h(x) + \hat{h}(x)$ for some $\hat{h}$. But this contradicts the previous paragraph, that says $v$ cannot depend on $x$.

Comment: More generally, if $u$ only depends on $x$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ must not depend on $x$, so $u(x)=ax+b$ for some real $a,b$.

Comment: i dont understand the last line in your answer. how can v(x,y)= ...?? i was lost there.

Comment: Anti-differentiate with respect to $y$.

Comment: what does h hat mean? can you give a little details there please as i am really new.

Comment: The idea is when you anti-differentiate, you need to account for constants. You might remember this from calculus. But when we're just differentiating with respect to $y$, then $x$ is a constant. So instead of just a adding a constant, it could be any function of $x$. There should be plenty of descriptions of multi-variable anti-differentiating on this site.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's impossible. The real (and imaginary) part of a holomorphic function is harmonic, and $x^x$ is not.

Comment: why is $x^x$ not harmonic?

Comment: Because its second derivative is non-zero. Recall that a function $u = u(x,y)$ is called **harmonic** if $\Delta u = u''_{xx} + u''_{yy} = 0$. In particular if $u$ is a harmonic function of two variables that is independent of $y$, $u''_{xx} = 0$, so $u$ must be affine which $x^x$ is not.